# MS Access, SQL Server backend - going to “create new record” on main form does not clear subform

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Current project:

- MS Access 2013/2016 32-bit front-end
- SQL Server 2012 back-end

We have migrated our data to a SQL Server database in preparation for creating a web based front end for internal use, however we are still using MS Access as the interface in the short term (for the next several months or so). Connection to the SQL Server database is made via an ODBC connection.

We have a problem with a form with a related subform. [The subform is properly linked to the main form](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/subforms/refresh.php) using the primary/foreign keys, and this *should* cause the subform to go blank whenever the main form goes to a blank/new entry. Unfortunately, that doesn’t happen - when going to a “create new record” on the main form, the subform *always* retains the content related to the last main record that was displayed.

Please note: this only happens when going to a “create new entry” on the main form. If all we do is switch between existing entries, the subform still switches to the correct related data (as it should) even if an entry has nothing in the subform. The problem is that when going to a “create new record” (blank main form), the subform retains the last displayed data when it should really be cleared.

Suggestions?

Comment: I would check if you can manually by opening the linked table to the main form see if you can freely add new records - and ensure that the autonumber PK is correctly being created.  This behaviour suggests that you are un-able to add new records.

Comment: Adding records is not the problem. We can add all the records we want without any issues at all. The problem exists in the subform - when we go to create the new record *through the primary form*, the subform continues to display the related content from the last record that was accessed -- it does not go blank as it should. In all other respects, the primary and sub forms behave exactly as expected.